# How to disable PageCache?

Tags: server, configuration, raid

I've got a system that collects a lot of data, than backs it up occasionally and pushes it to another server. My problem is that, while data collection process is taking 2-3% of memory, the rest of RAM fills up with PageCache, which causes problems for me.

`sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=1`

clears the memory, and I can set up chron job to clean it now and than, but this seems like inelegant solution. I'd rather disable the pagecache altogether on the raid disc that the app uses, or if that is not possible, on the whole server.

I've tried [this code](https://github.com/svn2github/pagecache-management) to start the app, and it doesn't work for me, pagecache keeps accumulating.

I'm running the program on Ubuntu server 20

How do I disable the PageCache on a hard drive/whole system?

*UPDATE*

Here's free over time:

```
>>> free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3981820      202180     3600504         852      179136     3565116
Swap:             0           0           0
>>>free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3981820      202336     3593204         852      186280     3561364
Swap:             0           0           0
>>>free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3981820      203132     3505208         852      273480     3547512
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Buff/cache continues growing until I flush the memory

```
>>>sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Amazon EC2
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       date: 10/16/2017
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 64KiB
       capabilities: pci edd acpi virtualmachine
  *-memory
       description: System memory
       physical id: 1
       size: 4GiB
```

```
>>>sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Comment: Where/how are you seeing the pagecache problem?

Comment: @heynnema I'm starting to get memory exceptions in the app around the time free system memory is almost empty

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: And reset your disk write-cache.

Comment: @heynnema updated. and how do I reset write-cache?

Comment: Reset write-cache by reversing the other answer. Your problem is you have no swap! Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @heynnema why do I need a swap if my program takes up max 3% of available memory, and it's the main program on the system?

Comment: ALL systems need swap. buff/cache is disk/file cache, and it's supposed to be large. Please show me the grep.

Comment: it's empty. I have none

Comment: by default, AWS instances come without swap

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I did some investigation into issue and found that the problem I was having when I was approaching the limit of free memory actually was that the program was hitting open file limit, so I ended up fixing that. Adding/removing swap didn't make any difference, neither did running a cronjob that would clean the memory

Comment: Excellent find! Thanks for the update. I updated my answer with your info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the nocache package:

```
sudo apt-get install nocache
```

Then run your process with the nocache command:

```
nocache whatever
```

This should control the cache build-up problem at the source.

Answer (score 2):

You have NO swap!

$ free

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        3981820      202180     3600504         852      179136     3565116
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Let's create a /swapfile...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

*I did some investigation into issue and found that the problem I was having when I was approaching the limit of free memory actually was that the program was hitting open file limit, so I ended up fixing that. Adding/removing swap didn't make any difference, neither did running a cronjob that would clean the memory.*

Answer (score 0):

To disable the write cache, try this:

Edit  /etc/hdparm.conf.

Uncomment the second of these two lines so that it looks like this:

```
# -W Disable/enable the IDE drive's write-caching feature
write_cache = off
```

To enable the write cache:

Edit  /etc/hdparm.conf.

Comment the second of these two lines so that it looks like this:

```
# -W Disable/enable the IDE drive's write-caching feature
# write_cache = off
```

Comment: what is the command to re-load configuration?

Comment: I've restarted the server with the new setting, and it still is having this issue

Comment: I don't think that disk write-cache is what OP is asking about.